# I only get one column of database in json format

Tags: python, json, django

My model is named Color has 4 columns,which is  Name & Background color & H1 color & P color.It is like
[image: actual table]

But now I only can get one column(it is Name) of database in json format.
It is like

```
[
    {
        "task_name": "white"
    },
    {
        "task_name": "green"
    },
    {
        "task_name": "pink"
    }
]
```

I want to get all columns of table in `json` format, but why can't I do it?

`models.py` is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    background_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    h1_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    p_color = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`serializers.py` is

```
from .models import Color
from rest_framework import serializers


class TaskSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    task_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100,source='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Color
        fields = ('name',
                  'background_color',
                  'h1_color',
                  'p_color',
                  'task_name')
```

`views.py` is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Color
from .forms import ColorForm
from .serializers import TaskSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    d = {
        'colors': Color.objects.all(),
        'form': ColorForm(),
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', d)

class TaskGet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    queryset = Color.objects.all()
```

I cannot understand why Name can be get,but other cannot be get.In `models.py`,I resignated all element.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Serializer` here that's why you are getting one field only in json. You have to use [`ModelSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

you have to use

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```